# JOOQ Query with comparing an jsonb element with ignore case on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jooq, jsonb

I'm using Jooq 3.18 and Postgres 14.

I have a Jsonb column that contains a string array such as `["A","B"]`.
I want to check in the where clause that the first element is equal (ignore case) to "a".

If I use the following condition in Jooq

```
DSL.jsonbGetElement(MY_TABLE.MY_JSONB_COLUM,0).equalIgnoreCase("a")
```

then I get no results.
The raw query looks like

```
lower(cast(("my_schema"."my_table"."my_jsonb_column"->0) as varchar)) = lower('a')
```

The cast breaks the query.

If I use containsIgnoreCase, then I get results. But also wrong matches.

```
DSL.jsonbGetElement(MY_TABLE.MY_JSONB_COLUMN, 0).containsIgnoreCase(JSONB.valueOf(JSONValue.toJSONString("a")
```

Just FYI, the generated query looks like this:

```
cast(("my_schema"."MY_TABLE"."MY_JSONB_COLUMN"->0) as varchar) ilike (('%' || cast('"a"' as varchar)) || '%') escape '!'
```

Does anyone know how I can do an equalsIgnoreCase with Jooq?

Comment: You probably want to generate `"my_schema"."MY_TABLE"."MY_JSONB_COLUMN"->>0` instead of the cast (notice `->>` instead of `->`), as otherwise the varchar will contain the json string delimiters (i.e. `"A"` not `A`). But I don't know jooq.

Comment: Yes, following works: `DSL.jsonbGetElement(MY_TABLE.MY_JSONB_COLUM,0).equalIgnoreCase("\"a\"")` Maybe there is a way to use ->>. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, that works, but if 'a' is dynamic, you probably don't want to have to JSON-encode it

Comment: I solved it: `DSL.jsonbGetElementAsText` generates the operator `->>`. Thanks!

Comment: You might want [post that as an answer](/help/self-answer) then. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: DSL.jsonbGetElementAsText generates the operator ->>. Thanks!